# Wrong camera position playing 360 degree video, using SceneKit and CoreMotion

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit, 360-virtual-reality

I am playing around with a 360 degree video player using SpriteKit, [SceneKit and CoreMotion.](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2016/05/10/implementing-a-360o-video-viewer-with-spritekit-and-scenekit/) The player is working so far, but the video is always zoomed-in a bit. It looks like the camera position is not at (0,0,0), but somehow wrong on the Z axis. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to adjust that. To reproduce the behavior just tap the screen, when the video is playing and pinch-zoom-out. This enables camera control with gestures, double tapping returns to camera control with the device.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import CoreMotion
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class Video360VC: UIViewController {
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

@IBAction func exitBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
performSegueToReturnBack()
}

func createSphereNode(material: AnyObject?) -> SCNNode {
    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 20.0)
    sphere.firstMaterial!.isDoubleSided = true
    sphere.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = material
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
    sphereNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0)
    sphereNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, Float.pi)
    return sphereNode
}

func configureScene(node sphereNode: SCNNode) {
    // Set the scene
    let scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // Camera, ...
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
}

func startCameraTracking() {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) {
        [weak self](data: CMDeviceMotion?, error: Error?) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        let attitude: CMAttitude = data.attitude

        self?.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(-   Float(attitude.roll + Double.pi/2), Float(attitude.yaw), -Float(attitude.pitch))
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "360Test2", withExtension: "mp4") else {
        print("Video File not found")
        return
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
    let videoNode = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: player)
    let size = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
    videoNode.size = size
    videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)

    let spriteScene = SKScene(size: size)
    spriteScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    spriteScene.addChild(videoNode)

    let sphereNode = createSphereNode(material:spriteScene)
    configureScene(node: sphereNode)
    guard motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable else {
        fatalError("Device motion is not available")
    }
    startCameraTracking()
    player.play()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.sceneView.play(self)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I used this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYTcrpiPEm0&disable_polymer=true) for testing, which can also be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlv3d8c6ashkljt/360Test2.mp4?dl=0).
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i can gather from your explanation is, that you have a problem with the so called `Field of View`. It may look like the camera is `zoomed` but actually it is not. Look for the FOV settings in your camera try settings like 90 degree.

Comment: Was exactly that ! SCNCamera has a property "fieldOfView", I set it to 90 degrees and it looked fine. `self!.cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView = 90`